# Is it possible to create multiple records using process builder?

Tags: process-builder

Can anyone Say is it possible to create multiple records using process builder?

Answer (score 1):

yes,you can create and update multiple records using process builder

Here is the example :- https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/auto-updating-child-records-process-builder

you can add multiple things in the process builder using this exmaple.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only Update more than one per Action, but not create. From experience this would require a Flow to loop create